# Downloading a file from a password protected site using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, download, password-protection

I am trying to download a file from a password protected site. I am using the following code, but when I run it nothing happens....no error, just nothing is downloaded. Any insights would be appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'
    }
    with requests.Session() as s:
        url1 = "http://....."
        url2 = "http://......tab"
        def login(url1, url2):
            r = requests.get(url1)
            bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            csrf_token = bs.find('input', attrs={'name': '###_CSRF-Token'})['value']
            credentials = {
                'username': '#####',
                'password': '#####',
                '###_CSRF-Token': csrf_token,
        }
            s.post(url1, data=credentials, headers=headers)
            resp = s.get(url2)
            with open('/Users/...../Website\ Grab/october.vcf', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
            #urllib.request.urlretrieve(url2, '/Users/.../Downloads/october.vcf')
```

Comment: In many cases the reponse for the posted credentials will contain a new cookie value which is a token you'll need to pass along with follow-up requests (i.e. the request to `url2`) - what that's called and whether that's exactly how it works in your case will depend on the site you're trying to access.

Comment: What is `login` meant to do? You don't use it anywhere.

Comment: @ Grismar I am new to requests...I thought using requests.session would store any cookies and pass them on? should use something else to deal with cookies? thank you!